# Get content in url with PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-split

I am fairly new to regex, and I am having a bit of a problem. I want the content in the url between the `/` and `?` or `/` and `/`.

Example:

`www.domain.com/about?page/readmore/party`

The values that I want:

`about`
`page`
`readmore`
`party`

How can I achieve this? Tried to do it with `preg_split` but could not achieve it.

Comment: `$url = str_replace ('?', '/', $url )` then `explode ('/', $url)` then `array_shift` to remove the domain part

Comment: of course! That I did not think about it. Can you reply that in an answer? I will give you an upvote ;)

Comment: See my answer below, please

Comment: What was the `preg_split` attempt? `preg_split('~[?/]~', $string)` i think will do it.

Comment: `preg_split` is slower as it uses the regexp system

Answer (score 2):

The ideea is that you replace the `?` character with the `/` to obtain `www.domain.com/about/page/readmore/party` then split by the `/` and obtain `[www.domain.com, about, page, readmore, party]`; then you just extract all but the first part with [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-slice.php):

```
    $url = 'www.domain.com/about?page/readmore/party';

    $parts = array_slice( explode ('/', str_replace ('?', '/', $url )), 1);

    var_dump( $parts );
```

it outputs:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "about"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "page"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "readmore"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "party"
}
```

see live [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4cf511e5a82f9664f7451ecb017443562b11fcbf)

Comment: Not quite what OP needs

Comment: This does exactly what I needed. I wanted the content between `?` and `/` and this does exactly that. Thanks constantin :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$urlStr = "www.domain.com/about?page/readmore/party";<br>
$newStr = str_replace("?","/",$urlStr);<br>
$newRep = explode("/",$newStr);<br>
$newArr = [];<br>
for($i = 0; $i < count($newRep); $i++){<br>
  if($i == 0){<br>
<br>
  }else{<br>
    array_push($newArr,$newRep[$i]);<br>
  }<br>
}<br>
print_r($newArr);<br>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Actually, I apologize for it because I'm newbie so I will remember your suggestion when I'll answer further any question and advance thanks for your suggestion

Comment: You can edit your answer here to include the relevant information.